# Pear Mail script not authenticating to send mail

Tags: php, email, pear

Howdie do,

I have a very simple script that is just suppose to email a confirmation email to users. However, I keep getting the following error:

*authentication failure [SMTP: Failed to write to socket: not connected (code: 250, response:  Hello localhost [127.0.0.1] SIZE 52428800 8BITMIME PIPELINING AUTH PLAIN LOGIN STARTTLS HELP)]*

The script is below. Pear mail has been installed. And yea, the password is correct, but I didn't place it in the script on here. Has anybody seen this error before?

```
function send_email($from, $to, $subject, $body)
{
  require_once "Mail.php";
  global $debug;

  $host = "localhost";
  $username = "user";
  $password = "*********";
  $headers = array
 (
  'From' => $from,
  'To' => $to,
  'Subject' => $subject
 );

 $smtp = Mail::factory
 (
  'smtp',
  array
  (
   'host' => $host,
   'auth' => true,
   'username' => $username,
   'password' => $password
   )
 );

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail) && $debug)
 {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 }
```

}

Edit:

The exim_mainlog is actually displaying this when the call goes through:

2013-09-06 15:50:51 SMTP connection from [127.0.0.1]:59845 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2013-09-06 15:50:51 SMTP connection from localhost [127.0.0.1]:59845 lost

Comment: So, what does the log file for your mail server say about this?

Comment: That's the thing, the maillog doesn't write anything to it about this when you submit the request. It's like it never even reaches the maillog

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I totally gave up on Pear::Mail and just converted the entire script to PHP_Mailer.

It's now working with no issue

```
 function send_email($from, $to, $subject, $body)
 {
   ini_set("include_path", ".:/home/user/public_html/PHPMailer_v2.0.4/");
   require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
   global $debug;
   $mailer= new PHPMailer();
   $mailer->IsSMTP();
   $mailer->Host = 'localhost';
   $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;

   $mailer->Username = "email";
   $mailer->Password = "*******";

   $mailer->FromName = "User";
   $mailer->From = "email";
   $mailer->AddAddress($to);
   $mailer->Subject = $subject;

   $mailer->Body = $body;

   if(!$mailer->Send())
   {
     //echo "Message was not sent";
     echo "Mailer Error: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
     exit;
   }
 }
```